# How can I call RefreshAll function when use GetObject function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use GetObject function to open one excel file in the background without opening.

```
   Dim exWb As Object
   Set exWb = GetObject("#.xls")
   exWb.RefreshAll
```

But it seems that `exwb` cannot refresh its data source.
Do we have any other way to refresh the background opened excel file?

Comment: There is one way that open the excel visibly. But it will influence the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't apply the RefreshAll method on workbooks without opening them.

`RefreshAll` is a method of `Workbook` object, so it needs you to open the workbook first.

Also, `GetObject()` Returns a reference to an object provided by an ActiveX component, so this example will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and do we have any other way to refresh the data without opening Excel file?

Comment: I have to ask why you would want to refresh the data without opening it? Is it just to avoid the delay on opening?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, to reduce the time cost and improve the user experience.